# Where does TFS creates the git repositories on the file system?

Tags: git, tfs

Does someone know where the Team Foundation Server 2017 creates the git repositories on it's file system? I want to migrate a few other repositories into my TFS installation but I need to know where the repositories are created (I don't mean my development machine, I mean the physicle path on the server itself).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. The repos are stored in the TFS database.

You can migrate existing repos by creating a new repo in TFS, adding a remote to it in your existing repo, and then force-pushing to the remote.

Comment: Is it also possible to move a Mercurial repository to the TFS Git this way? Or do I need to convert it first into Git?

Comment: @Sebastian TFS supports Git, not Mercurial. You'll have to convert your Mercurial repo to a Git repo in order to host it in TFS.